# how to check health of hard drives?

Tags: linux, hard-disk

How do I check the health of my hard drives?  I know that you can do it with system rescue, but is there a way to do it from root without booting onto system rescue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`smartmontools` is the package you are looking for. Using the `smartctl` command you could try:

```
sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda
```

Of course as mentioned below the drive needs to support SMART for information to be available, but whether it is supported/enabled will be in the output of the above command. If you look at the `man` page for `smartctl`, there are also various options for running self tests and enabling/disabling SMART etc.

Comment: Please, note that through most modern HDD's include SMART, some old ones may not. There's also the issue with SSD

Comment: @Braiam, what is the issue with SSD?